# Number of Unique Ice Cream Flavors Each Year

Tags: sql, join, merge, db2, where-clause

Here is a table with different ice cream flavors in different years (name: ice_cream_table):

```
Year      Flavor
2008         Mint
2008         Mint
2008 Cookie Dough
2008 Cookie Dough
2008    Pistachio
2013    Chocolate
2013 Cookie Dough
2013    Pistachio
2013    Chocolate
2013    Pistachio
2017    Chocolate
2017      Vanilla
2017    Chocolate
2017 Cookie Dough
2017   Strawberry
2019        Mango
2019       Lemon
2019      Vanilla
2019        Mango
2019        Mango
2022    Chocolate
2022    Chocolate
2022         Mint
2022   Strawberry
2022       Cherry

CREATE TABLE ice_cream_table  (
  "Year" INT,
  "Flavor" VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO ice_cream_table 
  ("Year", "Flavor")
VALUES
  ('2008', 'Mint'),
  ('2008', 'Mint'),
  ('2008', 'Cookie Dough'),
  ('2008', 'Cookie Dough'),
  ('2008', 'Pistachio'),
  ('2013', 'Chocolate'),
  ('2013', 'Cookie Dough'),
  ('2013', 'Pistachio'),
  ('2013', 'Chocolate'),
  ('2013', 'Pistachio'),
  ('2017', 'Chocolate'),
  ('2017', 'Vanilla'),
  ('2017', 'Chocolate'),
  ('2017', 'Cookie Dough'),
  ('2017', 'Strawberry'),
  ('2019', 'Mango'),
  ('2019', 'Lemon'),
  ('2019', 'Vanilla'),
  ('2019', 'Mango'),
  ('2019', 'Mango'),
  ('2022', 'Chocolate'),
  ('2022', 'Chocolate'),
  ('2022', 'Mint'),
  ('2022', 'Strawberry'),
  ('2022', 'Cherry');
```

In each year, I want to find out : How many flavors appear for the first time, how many flavors have appeared in previous years and how many distinct flavors (first time + repeated) are there?

Here is my code:

```
with yearly_flavor as (
    select 
        year,
        flavor,
        row_number() over (partition by flavor order by year) as rn 
    from 
        ice_cream_table 
    group by 
        flavor, year
),

new_flavor as (
    select
        year, 
        count(flavor) as new_flavor 
    from 
        yearly_flavor
    where 
        rn = 1
    group by 
        year
),

repeated_flavor as (
    select
        year, 
        case 
            when count(flavor) is null then 0 
            else count(flavor) 
        end as repeated_flavor,
        count(flavor) as new_flavor 
    from 
        yearly_flavor 
    where 
        rn > 1
    group by 
        year
),

total_flavor as (
    select
        year, 
        count(distinct flavor) as total_flavor 
    from 
        ice_cream_table
    group by 
        year
)

select 
    n.year,
    n.new_flavor,
    r.repeated_flavor,
    t.total_flavor
from 
    new_flavor n
left join 
    repeated_flavor r on n.year = r.year
join 
    total_flavor t on n.year = t.year
order by
    n.year;
```

My output:

```
+------+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| Year | new_flavor | repeated_flavor| total_flavor |
+------+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| 2008 | 3         | NULL           | 3            |
| 2013 | 1         | 2              | 3            |
| 2017 | 2         | 2              | 4            |
| 2019 | 2         | 1              | 3            |
| 2022 | 1         | 3              | 4            |
+------+-----------+----------------+--------------+
```

Am I doing it correctly? I am more experienced with Python and less with SQL ... the code runs, but I am not sure if my logic is capturing the essence.

Comment: *Am I doing it correctly* - well do you get the expected results?

Comment: Looks techincally correct but highly inefficient. You are joining three times when you only need to read the data once. There is a lot of extraneous code here: `case when count(flavor) is null then 0` is never going to happen, it will always be >= 0 not null. And `count(flavor) as new_flavor` on the next line is not true, because it's only counting repeated flavors, but luckily you are ignoring that column on the final select anyway.

Comment: I just compared our answers ... my result with the one you put on db<>fiddle ... I think both out answers are correct, but yours is more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` or `LAG` to find the first row per `flavor`, then group by `year` and count up.

This has the benefit compared to the other answer in that it only requires one scan of the base table.

```sql
SELECT
  Year,
  COUNT(IsFirst) AS NewFlavors,
  COUNT(DISTINCT Flavor) - COUNT(IsFirst) AS RepeatedFlavors,
  COUNT(DISTINCT Flavor) AS TotalFlavors
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Flavor ORDER BY Year) = 1 THEN 1 END AS IsFirst
    FROM ice_cream_table icf
) icf
GROUP BY
  Year;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/YnAaJAxo)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
select t.year, 
       count(distinct t.flavor) - count(distinct tt.flavor) as new_flavor,
       count(distinct tt.flavor) as repeated_flavor,
       count(distinct t.flavor) as total_flavor
  from ice_cream_table t
  left join ice_cream_table tt on t.year > tt.year and t.flavor = tt.flavor
group by t.year
```

Comment: If there is no new flavor(means all repeated flavor) in any year then your answer will not include that year in the result.